# Equivalent dplyr::slice in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a `df`:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 3, expr = runif(n = 20, min = 1, max = 7)))
```

And follow code:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  slice(4:7)

       x.1      x.2      x.3
1 6.357474 4.311422 1.633608
2 2.740982 6.908503 3.832040
3 6.668985 2.933429 3.396771
4 3.835659 4.637554 6.557594
```

How do this with a `spark_tbl` object? If I represent you directly, I have the message:

> Error in slice_.tbl_spark(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) :
> Slice is not supported in this version of sparklyr
> In addition: Warning message:
> `slice_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
> Please use `slice()` instead.

I need a function in `sparklyr` or **Spark function** to do this.

Comment: Does `df_1[4:7, ]` work?

Comment: No, the error message: `Error in df_1[4:7, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`